# Salesforce pushTopic creation issue for Streaming Api

Tags: salesforce

To get updates from salesforce **Account, Contact and AccountContacRole objects** into my **local database**. I have create **pushTopic** for **Account and Contact object** and receiving update messages using JAVA streaming client successfully. 
But when I was creating pushTopic for **AccountContactRole object** using following query in developer console.

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'ACRoleTableStreaming';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT AccountId,ContactId,IsDeleted,IsPrimary,Role FROM         AccountContactRole';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 30.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;`
```

I am getting following Error message.
**12:59:29:065 EXCEPTION_THROWN [10]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, 'AccountContactRole' is not supported: [Query]**

FYI I am using **salesforce developer account** and have also tries creating above pushTopic using https://workbench.developerforce.com.  **And Still gote same Error. i.e. "Error Creating Push Topic:
'AccountContactRole' is not supported."**
**Can anyone please tell me how can I create pushTopic for AccountContaactRole object 
or 
how can I get real time updates from this object into my local database using salesforce Streaming Client or any other method ?**

Answer (score 0):

Not all the objects are supported in `PushTopic` queries, and `AccountContactRole` is one of them. Please find the below quoted text from Salesforce Streaming API Guide:

> All custom objects are supported in PushTopic queries. The following subset of standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries: Account, Campaign, Case, Contact, Lead, Opportunity, Task. The following standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries through a pilot program: ContractLineItem, Entitlement, LiveChatTranscript, Quote, QuoteLineItem, ServiceContract."